# Mount Windows CIFS Share with smbclient?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, samba, smbfs

I'm trying to figure out how to share a network windows CIFS share ( I do not manage it ) with smbclient.

Initially I tried using the default Debian Lenny mounting application in Places->Connect to Server->Custom Location and I typed

```
smb://DOMAIN;meder@subdomain.maindomain.com/groups
```

(note: there's also a password to go along with my login)

So someone recommend to use smbclient except I did try various combinations based on interpreting my initial smb command but am not able to get the right syntax.

Someone mind helping? And also - what would I need to enter into /etc/fstab to perma mount?

Here's a screenshot on someone's Ubuntu of the exact error I receive while trying to copy it from the custom location mount:

[image]

*Update*

Thanks to caliban, I was able to actually connect with 'smbclient'. My currently dilemma is just having a permanent mount for that, here is my attempt at editing /etc/fstab:

Below my /dev/scd0 entry for my CD ROM Drive:

```
//subdomain.maindomain.com/share /mnt/share smbfs username=DOMAIN/meder,password=mypass,umask=0002 0 0
```

I actually had created /mnt/share as root with mkdir, was I supposed to do that?

And are there any log files I can view which would report it failing to mount that?

I restarted 3 times fully and I see empty files in /mnt/share, no error messages or anything.

**Solution:**

I actually modified the 'smbfs' in my /etc/fstab to be 'cifs' and it started working. I guess this means I'm not using smbfs/smb. It complained when I had it to 'smbfs' in /var/log/messages and said to read man mount.cifs.

Comment: er... wait. just saw the error, so you mean you can actually connect to the share??

Comment: I didn't have smbclient or smbfs when that happened, it was using some sort of default network connector application to try to connect to the smb. Then it was giving that, and someone said try smbclient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be smb://*domain*;*username*:*password*@*servername*/*foldername*

domain
username
password
servername
foldername

This is the proper syntax if everything works. So, if I want to connect to my fantasy share, it will be :

> smb://acmedefenses.com;caliban:12345678@battleplansserver/worlddomination

Not that this share exists, of course. :)

**EDIT : updated answer with a short primer on how to use smbclient to test connectivity**

To use smbclient to test connectivity, you can issue this command

> smbclient //*servername*/*foldername* -U *domain*/*username*
>
> smbclient //battleplansserver/worlddomination -U acmedefenses.com/caliban

To mount a SAMBA share in fstab, try this

```
//*servername*/*foldername* /mnt/samba smbfs username=*domain*/*username*,password=*password* 0 0

//battleplansserver/worlddomination /mnt/worlddom smbfs username=*acmedefenses.com/caliban,password=12345678 0 0
```

Comment: Sorry - am I supposed to use that or smbclient? Or would that already use smbclient? *foreheadslap* - I'm not on the actual network so I can't try it now.

Comment: smbclient is primarily used to *test* for connectivity - it's far more verbose than a simple Nautilus file explorer for example. :) Edited my answer to reflect.

Comment: Awesome; just tried smbclient and it worked. However I wasn't able to get the fstab / mounting part to work. I'll edit with my attempt.